# CommandLink is not in a jsf Form because i have added it to the template. However it is disabled. Is there an alternative way to enable it?

Tags: java, templates, jsf-2, xhtml

I have Added My **commandLink** (which is the logout link) into the template File which **is not** inside a **jsf form.**

MainTemplate.xhtml

```
<h:commandLink action="#{welcomeBean.logOutSession}" class="subAnchor" value="Log Out">
</h:commandLink>
```

on the webpage that uses the template, i have all the elements inside a jsf form:

NewWelcome.xhtml

```
<ui:composition xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
                 xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html"
                 xmlns:f="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/core"
                 xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
                 template="/webpages/templates/MainTemplate.xhtml">

  <ui:define name="infomationPartOfBody">
     <h:form>
<div>  Here i have all the page specific content </div>

 </h:form>
 </ui:define>

 </ui:composition>
```

I was hoping that the logout would work once i use the template in a page with a jsf form. However, the logout commandLink shows **error** :

*Log Out: This link is disabled as it is not nested within a JSF form.*

I know a clear solution is to add this element separately into each of the xhtml pages that would use the template. But i want it to be added into the template itself as it is a **common element** in all the pages.

Any help would be deeply appreciated. Thank You! :)

**Editing:**
here is the code of my MainTemplate.xhtml

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
  xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html"
 xmlns:f="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/core"
   xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets">
 <f:view>

    <h:head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/themes/cupertino/jquery-ui.css"/>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.0.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../JavaScriptPages/JQueryFile.js"></script>

        <title>State Transport Department- Work Schedule</title> 
        <link  rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../CSS/CompleteTemplateCSS.css"/>
    <link  rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../CSS/templateCSS.css"/>
    </h:head>

    <h:body>

        <div class="container">
            <div class="header">
                <h:graphicImage id="img"  value="http://s28.postimg.org/ksnr9zs5p/header.jpg" class="img" ></h:graphicImage> 
            </div>
            <div class="menu">
                 <h:outputLabel  class="welcomeNote" style="font-size: x-large; color: white; float: left;
                                margin: 8px 0 0 5px; text-shadow:0 0 3px white" value="#{welcomeBean.fullname}" />

         <ul class="ulForMyAccount">
                        <li> <h:outputLabel value="My Account" id="mainAnchor"/>

                            <ul >
                                <li> <h:link value="Change my Password" outcome="/webpages/ChangePasswordxhtml.xhtml" rendered="true" class="subAnchor"/>  </li>
                                <li><h:commandLink action="#{welcomeBean.logOutSession}" class="subAnchor" value="Log Out">
                             </h:commandLink> </li>

                            </ul>
                        </li>
                    </ul>     
            </div>
            <div class="contentBody">
                <div class="menuTable">

                    <table class="templateBody" >
                            <tr>
                                <td class="navigationLink" > <ul><li>
                                            <h:link  value="Home" outcome="/webpages/NewWelcome.xhtml"  rendered="#{welcomeBean.home}" class="mainLinks"/> 
                                        </li></ul> </td>

                            </tr>

                            <tr>
                                <td class="navigationLink"> <ul> <li>
                                            <h:link value="My Schedule" outcome="/webpages/MyTask.xhtml" rendered="#{welcomeBean.myTask}"   class="mainLinks"/>    
                                        </li></ul></td>
                            </tr>

                            <tr>
                                <td class="navigationLink"> <ul> <li>
                                            <h:link value="Employee Work Schedule" outcome="/webpages/EmpDutySched.xhtml" rendered="#{welcomeBean.workSchedule}"   class="mainLinks"/>    
                                        </li></ul></td>
                            </tr>

                            <tr>
                                <td class="navigationLink"><ul> <li>
                                            <h:link value="Allocate Work" outcome="/webpages/AllocateTask.xhtml" rendered="#{welcomeBean.allocateWork}" class="mainLinks"/>
                                        </li></ul></td>
                            </tr>

                            <tr>
                                <td class="navigationLink"><ul> <li>
                                            <h:outputLabel value="Report" rendered="#{welcomeBean.report}" class="reportMenu"/>

                                             </li></ul>
                                    <ul>
                                                <li><h:link value="Project Wise Report" outcome="/webpages/ProjectWiseReport.xhtml" rendered="true" class="reportItems"/></li>
                                                <li><h:link value="Employee Wise  Report" outcome="/webpages/EmployeeWiseReport.xhtml" rendered="true" class="reportItems"/></li>
                                            </ul>
                                       </td>
                            </tr>

                        </table>

                </div>

                <ui:insert name="infomationPartOfBody">

                </ui:insert>

            </div>

            <div class="footer"></div>
        </div>

    </h:body>

 </f:view>

</html>
```

Comment: Could you add the code of your template MainTemplate.xhtml ?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Since commandLink launch an action, you have to add a h:form

```
  <h:form>
 <h:commandLink action="#{welcomeBean.logOutSession}" class="subAnchor" value="Log Out"/>
 </h:form>
```

Comment: so do i just add tht logout button within jsf form or the whole of template? And wouldnt having a form in the template and the other pages create some kind of error? error of two forms existing etc?

Comment: Did you try this:
<li><h:form>
 <h:commandLink action="#{welcomeBean.logOutSession}" class="subAnchor" value="Log Out"/>
 </h:form></li>